# How to properly abstract Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm interested in how to properly abstract Firebase in order to decouple it with my app in case I want to switch back ends in the future.

Right now I have a single class with static methods that access the Realtime Database and Storage. I call these static methods throughout the app.

Is this the best way to use Firebase in a production environment? My app is written in Swift.

Comment: This is really impossible to answer. If you structure your app to work with Firebase, which is a online, asynchronous database, the entire code flow is based on that. If you switch to MySql, that's a totally different design pattern; not online (depending) and not asynchronous (generally). So it would a total re-write of most of the your database interaction (we've done it and have a LOT of first hand experience).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Wrapper class

```
class YourWrapperClass: NSObject {
}
```

Import the frameworks like Firebase that you want to use with this wrapper.

```
import Firebase
```

Create the methods with the use of Completion Handler/Closures/Blocks
That’s It. By this way you can use the code reusability.

Whenever you want to stop using Firebase, you will have to just stop calling methods from this wrapper class & implement alternative methods you want to call/use instead. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way here is to have `struct` with static members for each main node in your `Firebase database` and also separate models for each main folder of `Firebase storage`. It should look like `API's`. You can change it in the future without any problems.